# Setting a path when creating a new File in Java

Tags: java

I currently have the following code:

```
ImageIO.write(imageBlue, "PNG", new File("c://imageBlue.PNG"));
```

But I want the program to write it to my Desktop, no matter when Directory I am currently in.

Comment: Just use a absolute path to the desktop.

Comment: Can you use %userprofile%\\Desktop (when it is windows). Else there is probably a class that will is dependend determine the user home directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`System.getProperty(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) to get the [`user.home`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) *System Property*. Then, use that to get the `Desktop`. Finally, use that to get your desired output `File`. Something like,

```
String homeFldr = System.getProperty("user.home");
File desktop = new File(homeFldr, "Desktop");
ImageIO.write(imageBlue, "PNG", new File(desktop, "imageBlue.PNG"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Only this configuration needed,

```
ImageIO.write(imageBlue, "PNG", new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the path of to following :

```
C:\Users\{your-user-id}\Desktop
```