# How to add Icon Image on JButton

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class IconFrame extends JFrame{

    JButton Save,delete,Okay;
    IconFrame(){
    super("Icon Frame");    
        setTitle(" GUI");
        setSize(400,450);

        JLabel FirstName=new JLabel("Name");
        JLabel SecoundName=new JLabel("2nd Name");
        JTextField Firstname=new JTextField(10); 
        JTextField Secoundname=new JTextField(10);
        ImageIcon SaveIcon=new ImageIcon("save-icon.gif");
        ImageIcon deleteIcon=new ImageIcon("delete-icon.gif");
        ImageIcon OkayIcon=new ImageIcon("ok-512.gif");

        Save=new JButton("Save",SaveIcon);  
        delete =new JButton("delete",deleteIcon);
        Okay =new JButton("Okay",OkayIcon);

        JPanel pn=new JPanel();
        pn.add(FirstName);
        pn.add(Firstname);
        pn.add(SecoundName);
        pn.add(Secoundname);
        pn.add(Save);
        pn.add(delete);
        pn.add(Okay);
        add(pn);
    pack();

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IconFrame obj=new IconFrame();  
    }

}
```

Not getting it why it is not Showing me image on my JButton
Save delete and ok-512 are my Images located on Desktop.

Comment: where is ur java class located?

Comment: what do you see? Do you get an error message?

Comment: refer my answer over here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36264055/setting-a-path-when-creating-a-new-file-in-java/36264149#36264149

Comment: All my classes are in my document workspace

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some are correct, others are not. Learn and follow the standards!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your images into your project in your workspace and access it using getResource() method,which returns the url of the image.

For example: if your image is inside a folder named "resource" under "src",you can access it from your class using the below code:

```
ImageIcon SaveIcon=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
                "/resources/save-icon.gif"));
```

This should fetch the image.

Comment: The method getimg(String) is undefined for the type Class

 at IconFrame.<init>(IconFrame.java:11)
 at IconFrame.main(IconFrame.java:37)

Comment: it is saying The method getimg(String) is undefined for the type Class

 at IconFrame.<init>(IconFrame.java:11)
 at IconFrame.main(IconFrame.java:37)

Comment: where are you using the getimg(String) method.don't see that in the code you shared.can you update your code, with modifications if any?

Comment: O yes Man its Works Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do following changes into your code **if images are located on Desktop then,**,

```
String desktopPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Desktop" +File.separator;

ImageIcon SaveIcon=new ImageIcon(desktopPath + "save-icon.gif");
ImageIcon deleteIcon=new ImageIcon(desktopPath +  "delete-icon.gif");
ImageIcon OkayIcon=new ImageIcon(desktopPath +  "ok-512.gif");
```